# Custom modules are not found when calling python script in console VS pycharm

Tags: python

I have a python3 script that I am calling in terminal; I do not use `Python` prefix to run it, since I did add `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` in my script (I have python3 from brew, on OSX).

The interesting thing is that if I run the script in terminal, I get an import error because one of my custom module hasn't been found. If I run the same script in pycharm, it works fine.

I assume Python launch and read all the various path that I use for modules in the same way, in both pycharm and terminal, but it seems not the case. How do I set up my scripts so the modules are found, independently from their path?

I may run the same script from other machines too, so I want to be prepared and do the right thing from the start.

EDIT
I am running pycharm on OSX; Python3 is installed via Brew, but the symlink is in /usr/local/bin.
My script is running from a folder inside my home directory, so 
`/Users/tester/git/python_test_app/main/base/app_main.py`

The custom modules are in the same folder of the main py script, but one level above: `/Users/tester/git/python_test_app/main/pyutils.py`

The import statement from `app_main.py` is 
`import main.pyutils as utilities`

This is the stack trace that I get when running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main/base/app_main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import main.pyutils as utilities
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

EDIT 2 and solution

Thanks to The answers, I was able to figure out that the issue is related to how Pycharm handle projects. Basically it somehow save the path where the project is; so calling an import will result in the project folder being parsed, and that's why it works fine from Pycharm.

In Python, unless `PYTHONPATH` has the path to my project or other modules that I wrote, it won't be able to find them, hence, raise the error.

FIX:

in my main module that I use to run the application, I did retrieve the path of the file; which I know being one level below the modules I need; so I can explicitly add the folder to the current `sys.path`. This will end up making possible for me to call the import successfully.

```
import sys

current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, , current_dir)
```

The only downside is that every file and resource that I use in my project, has to be directly referred by full path; so I have to pass the `current_dir` around the various files in the project.

Comment: It is hard to tell unless you update your question with the location of your script, the location of the faulty module and the full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @PauloScardine; updating the question accordingly

Comment: Have you tried `import ..main.pyutils` ?

Comment: @EvyatarMeged in Python3 I get an error of incorrect syntax when using the dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm has project interpreter settings. Verify these are the same as your system Python. Go to:

1. File menu
2. Settings
3. Project: `<project name>`
4. Project Interpreter
5. View the path to the Python executable/binary being used by the project in PyCharm and verify it matches what your system is calling (e.g., `which python3`)

Alternatively, it may be that you declared your sources root within PyCharm and the system cannot properly run the module as it exists in the path you're running it from (especially if inside a package). You can get around this using the `-m` parameter and calling it from Python.

You can also try running it from the Terminal inside PyCharm and see what it adds to the path before initializing the shell session (you can sometimes see this in your Run configurations also). If you are referring to modules not installed via pip / into the Python path but rather loaded into your project path, then this may be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I did find out that the paths are all correct; but for some reason, pycharm is setting a variable that refer to the location of the project. This result in pycharm knowing that when I call `import X`, it is somewhere in my project folder. Python instead has no clue; so unless the module is in the PYTHONPATH variable, it will raise an error. Thanks for pointing me to the right place!

Answer (score 0):

On PyCharm, next to the green "RUN" arrow press the box and then press edit configurations (see image)

[image]

There you'll have `Working Directory` - that path is where PyCharm is running that script from (without errors).

Try running it from the terminal within that path - that should solve your import errors.